# i'm getting ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 5) when i'm using torch.onnx.export method

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, onnx

the model works but i'm failing to export it to onnx, my goal is to convert it to onnx then to tflite, for the model i've used torch implementation of tacotron

```
model = model.cuda()
dummy_input = torch.randn(30, 256, 425, 80, 2)
torch.onnx.export(model,dummy_input ,"myModel.onnx", verbose=True, input_names='input', 
output_names='output')
```

the output

```
/content/tacotron2/model.py in forward(self, inputs)
    498 
    499     def forward(self, inputs):
--> 500         text_inputs, text_lengths, mels, max_len, output_lengths = inputs
    501         text_lengths, output_lengths = text_lengths.data, output_lengths.data
    502 
    ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 5)
```

Comment: It seems your input doesn't conform to your forward implementation. The input is meant to contain a total of five elements for each batch element: `text_inputs, text_lengths, mels, max_len, output_lengths = inputs`.

Comment: so, the error is being thrown b/c of my model? not the export method in or my arguments

Comment: The error is thrown because the input doesn't have the correct format. It should hold a total of five elements.